# How to hook functions that aren't in the Win32 API?

Tags: c++, assembly, hook, reverse-engineering, dll-injection

I made a very simple program that create a windows and display "Random number is: [random number from 0 to 9]" in the top left corner. The function that display the number looks like this:

```
void DisplayThings(HDC hdc, HWND hWnd, int randomNum)
{
    std::stringstream text;
    text << "Random number is: " << randomNum;
    TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, text.str().c_str(), text.str().length());
}
```

In OllyDBG, I found it at the address 0x11211A0:

[image: DisplayThings function]

Next, I made a dll that tries to detour the DisplayThings function with the help of Microsoft Detour, here is what the dll looks like:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "detours.lib")

#include <Windows.h>
#include <detours.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <sstream>

typedef void (*pDisplayThingsFunc)(HDC hdc, HWND hWnd, int randomNum);
void DisplayThingsFunc(HDC hdc, HWND hWnd, int randomNum)
{
    printf("function is being detoured\n");
    TextOut(hdc, 0, 20, L"detoured", 8);
}
pDisplayThingsFunc DisplayThingsFuncToDetour = (pDisplayThingsFunc)(0x11211A0);

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved  )
{
    //DWORD *hiddenValueAdress = (DWORD*)(*(DWORD*)0x020FAB8);

    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:

        AllocConsole();
        freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);

        DetourTransactionBegin(); 
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());

        DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)DisplayThingsFuncToDetour, DisplayThingsFunc);

        DetourTransactionCommit();

        break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        FreeConsole();

        DetourTransactionBegin(); 
        DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());

        DetourDetach(&(PVOID&)DisplayThingsFuncToDetour, DisplayThingsFunc);

        DetourTransactionCommit();
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Once I inject the dll, the address get correctly replaced with a JMP to my new functions, but then something weird happens... The console keep printing "function is being detoured" but the TextOut function fails to display anything...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by ´keeps printing´? Does it print it repeatedly?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your hooked function in Olly after it was hooked? (JMP detour should take you to your hook function) When you're in your hook function in Olly, try to see if the arguments are properly passed to TextOut function.

Comment: @user35443 - "function is being detoured" is being printed every 5 seconds, so it match with how many times the function should be detoured.

Comment: @blackd0t - Yea I've tried stepping through it and the arguments are definitely not passed properly, but I don't know why. For instance, I tried printing the third arguments (int randomNum), and while it should be a number between 0 and 9, it returns 138000... Any idea why?

Comment: I have two shots to night: 1. Compiler may use some different calling conventions, maybe you can try to force compiler to use only one of them. 2. compiler may be optimizing your function (passing some arguments to registers).

Comment: This isn't really my area of expertise, but I'm using the same compiler for both my dll and my program and I didn't change any configurations, so wouldn't it be weird if the compiler used a different calling conventions?

Comment: here i hook a function not in the win32 api, using ollydbg and writing the assembly codes directly.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093398/win32-how-can-i-hook-functions-in-compiled-programs-with-c

but i guess you, like me, want to know how to hook it from c++, not how to make an assembly code hook :p

Answer (score -1):

The compiler is optimizing the code, because it deduced that it could safely do so for this function.

- It is not exported.
- It is not used with function pointers.
- It is not used outside the scope that is analyzed. (Depends on compiler settings)
- There is most likely only one caller (if there are more different callers with different settings it's less likely that arguments get optimized away).

You could change one of those things (for example by exporting the symbol, by assigning it to a function pointer etc..).

Or you could try to hook it as-is now.

First you need to deduce where the argument you are interested in is getting passed trough, [which is most likely a register.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xa169sk.aspx)
The easiest way to do this is to analyze the call to TextOut and trace the hdc argument back.
If you are lucky and it got optimized simply by making it fastcall, change the type of both your function and your function pointer to fastcall, and be done.

If you are not that lucky, you might have to grab it from an extra register with inline assembly.

Comment: The compiler isn't optimizing out the code, you can see by the fact that half the function gets executed correctly, the printf call. It's the TextOut call that fails, probably because the arguments aren't being passed correctly. The reason why the compiler doesn't optimize the code is because the address of the function is taken in the call to DetourAttach.

Comment: I said optimizing the code, not optimizing the function out.

Comment: And there is no reason at all for the compiler to not optimize the code, because the DetourAttach takes an absolute address, not the address of the function, and the DetourAttach is in a seperate dll, not the main application.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to apply the most reasonable interpretation of what you meant by "optimizing the code".  Otherwise your post meaningless as it doesn't show how whatever you mean by "optimizing the code" would cause anything resembling the behaviour described.

Comment: That follows out of the second part, namely that it most likely uses registers for argument-passing.

Comment: It can't use anything other the default (cdecl) calling convention because the function is global. It has no idea what else might call it.

Comment: there is a commandline option for that: /GL (Whole Program Optimization)

Comment: You're grasping at straws. Even in the unlikely case that the original poster actually used that option with his simple test case, the compiler can't assume that `detours.lib` or something else linked in doesn't call it. There's also the fact that a pointer to the function is passed to DetourAttach, but apparently you don't understand what that means.

Comment: I do understand that perfectly fine, but you do not seem to understand that a pointer that is referenced in a dll does not influence a separate application.

Comment: If you understood what pointers to functions are you'd realize a pointer to DisplayThingsFunc is used twice in the DllMain function shown above. The address of the function escapes the code through the use of the pointer as an argument to an external function so the compiler cannot change its calling convention. You also don't understand that both DetourAttach and DisplayThingsFunc are linked together in the same DLL, and not in a separate DLL and application. The compiler can't assume DetourAttach or something else in the library `detours.lib` doesn't link to and call DisplayThingsFunc.

Comment: How about you look at the code before commenting?

The original code is in an application, the code that hooks into it is in a dll.

DisplayThingsFunc is the function that is called instead of the original function, and not at all the target of concern here.

Comment: The function DisplayThings is the target of the detour (e.g. the one being edited / overwritten), and this is the function that is getting optimized because noone references it.

Comment: Ugg... I finally see your point. If you had you at any point previously stated you were talking about the optimization of the function that was executing correctly instead of the function that was executing incorrectly this could have been cleared up much sooner. Indeed the problem you're suggesting is happening would caused by the optimizations made in the unseen caller of DisplayThings (and so also the caller of the detour). However my comments about "it' being a global function preventing these optimizations still apply.